# Renouncing ownership without implemented function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, smart-contract-wallets

I already deployed a contract using openzepellin and since it is being used, is it possible to renounce the ownership ? I did forgot to add the renounceOwnership function or transferOwnership.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So ownership only works if you are using the Ownable contract directly or by extending with:

```
contract MyContract is Ownable {...}
```

Only if you are using that or any other form of access control renouncing ownership makes sense since owners usually have some kind of special privileges.

In short, if you are using [Ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol), the functions are there, no need to implement. If you are not using it, or any other form of access control, you cannot renounce it because there is no address who "Owns", or has special privileges, in the contract.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
I do use the Ownable & I do see my wallet as the owner when i do interact with the contract on ethscan for example, but how do I renounce it when I cannot find the option for it while "Writing Contract" on EthScan ?

Comment: Take another look. It should be there. The Ownable.sol contract has that function by default. I could take a look at the verified contract on etherscan if you want, just need the address

Comment: Yes sure 0x7FE65F4C63ce1FEB6a84a30Fa491fA60BA11B1E8

Comment: Verify the contract and you will see it

Comment: I did verify the contract on ethscan, It is Ownable since I did use some ownable functions, but I didnt import the Ownable.sol & I cannot see any option for transferring the ownership unless its a bout transferring tokens function

Comment: If anyone could help me renounce it, i'll gladly pay